# Random().nextBool() works in a silly way. How do I solve it?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import '6veritabani_islemleri.dart';

main(List<String> args) {
  VeritabaniIslemleri db = VeritabaniIslemleri();

  bool sonuc = db.connect();

  if (sonuc == true) {
    print("Connected");
  } else {
    print("Not connected.");
  }
}
```

```
import 'dart:math';

class VeritabaniIslemleri {
  String _kullaniciAdi = "arda";
  String _sifre = "123456";

  bool connect() {
    print("internet connection:");
    print(isThereInternet());
    if (isThereInternet() == true) {
      if (_kullaniciAdi == "arda" && _sifre == "123456") {
        return true;
      } else
        return false;
    } else
      return false;
  }

  bool isThereInternet() {
    bool deger = Random().nextBool();
    if (deger) {
      return true;
    } else
      return false;
  }
}
```

In the second part, if isThereInternet() function returns false, shouldn't connect() function automatically returns false? But in my code even if isThereInternet() returns false, connect() can returns true.

When I change Random().nextBool() to false or true bool value, the code works fine. Why? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code call `isThereInternet()` twice, so it generates two result, And the two results may be different.
I have modified you code a little:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

class VeritabaniIslemleri {
  String _kullaniciAdi = "arda";
  String _sifre = "123456";

  bool connect() {
    print("internet connection:");
    final hasInternet = isThereInternet();
    print(hasInternet);
    if (hasInternet) {
      if (_kullaniciAdi == "arda" && _sifre == "123456") {
        return true;
      } else
        return false;
    } else
      return false;
  }

  bool isThereInternet() {
    return Random().nextBool();
  }
}
```

Comment: Which parts my code calls two times isThereInternet()? Thanks in advance.

Comment: print() one time and if the other time.